# Why is my python Magnetometer calibration code not working for Soft Iron disturbance?

Tags: python, stm32, magnetometer

I've been trying to visualize magnetometer calibration from my STM32F3 board. I send raw 3-axis (Unsigned 16 bit per axis) through USB to be read, converted to 16 bit signed float, calibrated and finally plotted in my python code. When I plot the calibrated magnetometer data, the hard iron offset seems to work (since the graph is centered at (0,0)) but the soft iron ellipse does not transform into a circle which really confuses me. I am new to python so I think that is where my error may be. I'm following the equations (6) & (7) from this paper [here](http://www.brokking.net/YMFC-32/YMFC-32_document_2.pdf) and here is my python code below and my "calibrated results"

(Magnitude doesn't matter for me so units are raw sensor integers and not in Gauss).

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#USB Com Port 16bit signed integer Communication 
s = serial.Serial('COM4')

magx = []
magy = []
magz = []

for i in range(0, 250):
    
    ret = s.read(6)
    magx.append(np.int16((np.uint16(ret[0]) << 8) + ret[1]))
    magy.append(np.int16((np.uint16(ret[2]) << 8) + ret[3]))
    magz.append(np.int16((np.uint16(ret[4]) << 8) + ret[5]))
    
    time.sleep(0.05)

s.close()

#Calibaration terms
Xmax = max(magx)
Xmin = min(magx)

Ymax = max(magy)
Ymin = min(magy)

Xsf = (Ymax - Ymin) / (Xmax - Xmin)
Ysf = (Xmax - Xmin) / (Ymax - Ymin) 

if Xsf < 1:
    Xsf = 1
if Ysf < 1:
    Ysf = 1

Xoff = ((Xmax - Xmin)/2 - Xmax) * Xsf
Yoff = ((Ymax - Ymin)/2 - Ymax) * Ysf

print("Xsf = ",Xsf,"Ysf = ",Ysf,"\r")
print("Xoff = ",Xoff,"Yoff = ",Yoff,"\r\r")

for i in range(0, 250):
    magx[i] = magx[i]*Xsf + Xoff
    magy[i] = magy[i]*Ysf + Yoff


plt.grid()
plt.scatter(magx, magy, marker="o",c='w',edgecolors='r')
plt.show()
```

[image: "Calibrated Magnetometer Data Image"]

Comment: That looks like a circle to me.  The plot has a non-square aspect ratio that's stretching the visual depiction of the circle, but the axis labels show that it goes from -190 to 190 on both axes.

Comment: So that's it... I added: " plt.gca().set_aspect("equal") " and it now shows a circle. Thanks Jason!